# andengine: transparent png turns black

Tags: android, png, andengine

I'm working on a dress-up game for android. I'm using andEngine and totally new to it. I'm trying add a png that has a transparent background. The problem is, transparency turns to black.
I created the resources, where I created the bitmapTextureAtlas and two TextureRegions; one of them is the background and the other is the girl model...
In the step of assigning the textureRegions to a sprite.. I find that without assigning the background to the sprite it doesn't appear. but the other texture (model) I didn't assign it to a sprite but it's visible!! and the transparent background of it turns black!!!

Any ideas?!!

Comment: have you added hardware acceleration in manifest.xml

Comment: I was trying to find out what's wrong? I still couldn't get why the textures are visible after the onCreate Resources without adding them to a sprite. But I found that when adding the background to the atlas (held by a sprite) and then adding another picture (sprite) this cuts part of the background and doesn't add on it... so I solved this issue by creating an Atlas for the background alone and Another Atlas for the pictures on the top... It worked :) but does it make sense to ahave many atlases for the same scene?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have two atlases on the same screen imo. Are you sure you are decoding ARGB and not RGB, you might be decoding in a way that doesn't recognize alpha. Haven't used andEngine so I'm just guessing here...

Comment: Actually, I found that the prblem wasn't that the transparent turns black, but the transparent is on a black surface so it shows it's color. It's weird because it supposed to be on a colored background (image).. but what happened that it erased the background image and was placed on the area cut.. 
When I added another atlas, it worked well.. but I feel it's nonsense, that's mainly what I'm asking about

Comment: @dineshsharma I don't understand what this and what does it do (Hardware acceleration)

Answer (score 0):

Now I got it :)
The Atlases and ITextureRegion are not to be displayed on screen, but to be stored in memory, ITextureRegion comes to life and stage by sprites..

The problem was that I was placing the ITextureRegion at coordinates (0,0) for all of them, so my images where almost destroyed, so I overcomed this problem by using BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas so that it takes care of where every TR is placed on the Atlas without caring about placing them manually. And Also I used just one atlas that can fit all my images, I didn't have to use two